# why i am not getting output as hello

Tags: c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string f = "Hello";
string z{} ;
for(int i =0;i<f.size();i++){
    if(f[i]>'A' && f[i]<='Z'){
        z[i] = f[i]+32;
    }
    else{
        z[i] =  f[i];
    }
}
cout<<z;
```

}

I am trying to pass Hello
but not getting output as hello
basically want to covert all characters to lower string

Comment: `z` is an empty string, therefore `z[i]` is trying to access it out of bounds. The behavior of the program is thus undefined.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the way you initialize the `z` string in your case is initialized using the brace initialization syntax which sets all elements to their default value which is the empty string in this case and with it your code tries to access the `i` index element of z in the for loop which is not possible since z is still an empty string here's a solution using the `push_back()` method with it you can add characters to the end of the z string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string f = "Hello";
    string z;
    for(int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++)
    {
        if(f[i] > 'A' && f[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            z.push_back(f[i] + 32);
        }
        else
        {
            z.push_back(f[i]);
        }
    }
    cout << z;
}
```